# How to load 3 items in an array to simulate a Lazy ZStack?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I am trying to figure out a way to simulate a lazy zstack. I know it's not possible to create a lazyZStack. I want to display user profile images and to increase performance I want to make sure it only loads the first 3 users when the first one is discarded it loads another behind the last two.

SwipeView

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwipeView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = SwipeViewModel()
     
    var body: some View {
            
            ZStack {
                
                ForEach(viewModel.users) { user in
                        
                        CardView(photo: user.profileImageURL)
   
                }
            }
           
        }
       
    }
struct SwipeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwipeView()
    }
}
```

CardView

```
import SwiftUI
import Kingfisher

struct CardView: View {
    
    @State private var offset = CGSize.zero
    @State private var color: Color = .black
    @State private var radius: CGFloat = 10
    @State private var size: CGFloat = 370
    
    
    var photo: String = ""
    var name: String = ""
    

    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
                KFImage(URL(string: photo))
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: size)
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .shadow(color: color, radius: radius, x: 2, y: 5)
                    .padding(.top)
                    .offset(x: offset.width, y: offset.height * 0.4)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(Double(offset.width / -80))) // ROTATION AMOUNT
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture()
                            .onChanged { gesture in
                                offset = gesture.translation
                                withAnimation {
                                    changeColor(width: offset.width)        
                                }      
                            }.onEnded { _ in
                                withAnimation {
                                    swipeCard(width: offset.width)
                                    changeColor(width: offset.width)}})
            }
    }
//MARK: - SWIPE CARD FUNCTION
func swipeCard(width: CGFloat) {
    switch width {
    case -1000...(-150):
        
        offset = CGSize(width: -1000, height: 0)
    case 150...1000:
        
        offset = CGSize(width: 1000, height: 0)
    default:
        offset = .zero
    }
}

func changeColor(width: CGFloat) {
    switch width {
    case -500...(-50):
        color = .red
        radius = 40
        
    case 50...500:
        color = .green
        radius = 40
        
    default:
    color = .black
    radius = 8
    
    }
}
            
    }
```

Doubt this will be needed but: SwipeViewModel

```
import Foundation

class SwipeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var users = [User]()

    let service = UserService()
    init() {
       fetchUsers()
    }
    
    func fetchUsers() {
        service.fetchUsers { users in
            self.users = users
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried different solutions, nothing seems to be working for me. Hopefully someone here could help?
Thanks in advance!